# MID-attributes dump from freebase

Tags: freebase

I downloaded the freebase triples from https://developers.google.com/freebase/data
But then i have no idea how to convert the MID to the actual entity name like  /m/02hl8db is mapped to "Burgertime".
Is there any dump available on freebase side which provides all attributes associated with mid.My use case is to find all product names and the companies that own that product. Similarly i also want to extract all names of persons and the name variants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Freebase triples (ie RDF) dump **is** that dump.  The format is subject MIDproperty/predicateobject, so if you have an object MID that you want an attribute of (e.g. it's name), just find the appropriate triple with that as the subject MID.

Here's what all the property values look like for that subject:

```
ns:cvg.game_version     ns:type.type.instance   ns:m.02hl8db.
ns:m.02hl8db    ns:type.object.type     ns:cvg.game_version.
ns:m.02hl8db    ns:cvg.game_version.game        ns:m.01xq80.
ns:m.02hl8db    ns:type.object.name     "Burgertime"@en.
ns:m.02hl8db    ns:type.object.type     ns:common.topic.
ns:m.02hl8db    ns:cvg.game_version.platform    ns:m.01145.
ns:m.02hl8db    rdfs:label      "Burgertime"@en.
ns:m.02hl8db    rdf:type        ns:cvg.game_version.
ns:m.02hl8db    rdf:type        ns:common.topic.
```

as well as those triples where it is the object

```
ns:m.01xq80     ns:cvg.computer_videogame.versions      ns:m.02hl8db.
ns:m.01145      ns:cvg.cvg_platform.games_on_this_platform      ns:m.02hl8db.
```

When converting IDs that you see on Freebase.com, whether they be type/property IDs or topic IDs, just remember to replace the slashes with dots when looking for them in the RDF dump.